# Use Elasticsearch as backup store

Tags: elasticsearch, backup

My application receives and parse thousands of small JSON snippets each about ~1Kb every hour. I want to create a backup of all incoming JSON snippets.

Is it a good idea to use Elasticsearch to backup this snippets in an index with f.ex. `"number_of_replicas:" 4`? Never read that anyone has used Elasticsearch for this.

Is my data safe in Elasticsearch when I use a cluster of servers and replicas or should I better use another storage for this use case?

(Writing it to the local file system isn't safe, as our hard discs crashes often. First I have thought about using HDFS, but this isn't made for small files.)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find **difference between replica and backups**.

**replica** is more than one copy of data at run time.It increases high availability and failover support,it wont support accidental delete of data.

**Backup** is copy of whole data at backup time.it will be used to restore when system crashed.

Elastic search for back up.. its not good idea.. **Elastic search is a search engine not DB**.If you have not configured ES cluster carefully,then you will end up with loss of data.

So in my opinion ,
To store json object, we got lot of dbs.. For example mongodb is a nosql db.We can easily configure it with more replicas.It means high availability of data and failover support.As you  asked its also opensource and more reliable. 
for more info about mongodb refer https://www.mongodb.org/

**Update:**
In elasticsearch if you create index with more shards it'll be distributed among nodes.If a node fails then the data will be lost.But in mongoDB more node means ,each mongodb node contains its own copy of data.If a mongodb fails then we can retrieve out data from replica mongodbs. We need to be more conscious about replica setup and shard allocation in Elasticsearch. But in mongoDB it's easier and good architecture too.

**Note:** I didn't say storing data in elasticsearch is not safe.I mean, comparing to mongodb,it's difficult to configure replica and maintain in elasticsearch.

Hope it helps..!

Comment: Thanx; I already use Elasticsearch to index text in my application, so I thought I could use another Elasticsearch-cluster for taking backups and keep my technology stack small without needing another DB . But maybe you are right and it's a better idea to use something like MongoDB for this. But why should the data in Mongo be more safe than in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't see the point why configuring the replicas in Elasticsearch is difficult. I found it very easy.

Comment: If you create a replica for an index then it won b allocated till u run a new node...  And if u start d another node the shards will b shared among node..  If a newly started nose down means Den data in new node Ll b lost.. Until d new node is up..